# Problems with my app's login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have done a login for my app, so, to finish it, I modified the method didfinishlaunching from the delegate. 
In this method, I take the session from the userdefaults and check if is valid(calling to my server). If it's correct, I load the main viewcontroller, if not, the login viewcontroller.

The problem is that in the method didfinishlaunching I dont load any viewcontroller, because I am waiting the response from the server. I load the viewcontrollers in the connection's delegate. This causes me 2 problems:

- An error telling me I have to have one main view controller loaded
- If I do, I put an viewcontroller, the time that I am waiting the response that viewcontroller is displayed, and it's very ugly.

I think that one solution may be to do another viewcontroller, only with a loading bar, and load it while I wait the response...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly what you are talking about in an app I've made: at the beginning I create a "SplashScreenViewController", that has an UIImageView equal to the image I use as a splashscreen for my app.
Here I have a loading wheel and I load every kind of data I need. When I receive every data I need, I load my root controller.

You can do the same, but you can load your controller relating to the session status.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can show one of view controllers but add some overlay view with activity indicator, and when you get response just remove overlay and reload your view controller according to response.

Answer (score 1):

while the nsmainthred is processing, create a new nsthred to create a view loading and add in subview from your view controller. When you get the response remove this view from super view
and depending your response, call your other view controller